# Make osascript print stdout interactively / in real-time

Tags: python, terminal, applescript, stdout, osascript

Ok, so I have this very simple python script:

```
import time
import sys

for i in range(25):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(i)

sys.exit()
```

When I use python to run it (`/usr/local/bin/python3.6 testscript.py`), all works fine and the output reads:

```
1
2
3
4
etc..
```

With each number printed 1 second after the other.

However when I run:

```
/usr/bin/osascript -e 'do shell script "/usr/local/bin/python3.6 testscript.py" with prompt "Sart Testing " with administrator privileges'
```

There isn't any output for 25 seconds and finally it prints:

```
24
```

To the terminal.

**The question is:** How can I make osascript print the exact same output as when I run the Python script directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AppleScript's** `do shell script` *command* runs in a non-interactive shell, so you cannot execute the `osascript` *command* as you have it and expect it to output the same as running the `python` *script* via `python` or run directly. In other words, directly being adding the `python` *shebang* and making the file executable and thus `./testscript.py` in **Terminal** is all you need. Or do it with **Terminal** and its `do script` *command* with `osascript`.

Save the `python` *code* as. e.g.:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.6

import time
import sys

for i in range(25):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(i)

sys.exit()
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod u+x testscript.py
```

Run it in Terminal:

```
./testscript.py
```

Or:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "/path/to/testscript.py"'
```

Or the `python` *code* without the *shebang* and not made executable while using **Terminal's** `do script` *command*:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "/usr/local/bin/python3.6 /path/to/testscript.py"'
```

Comment: Thnx for your reply, problem is: I am launching osascript via subprocess.Popen in another Python script. Goal is this: python_script1 runs a GUI that can launch python_script2 with sudo rights and then adds a single step to the progress bar whenever script 2 writes a line to stdout. I got this setup to work as expected as long as I leave osascript out but I need a clean, easy & native way to ask for sudo password when launching the second script.

Comment: I realize my comment is in fact another question altogether, but I figured if there is a way to get osascript to just print the output to stdout my problem would be solved.

Comment: Started a new question that is directly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49171769/4041795