# How & where to best retrieve sudo password via a native GUI on a macOS Python-based app - (while maintaining an interactive output stream (stdout))

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, applescript, osascript

Ok, so the situation is this: I am building a macOS GUI App using Python and wx (wxphoenix). The user can use the GUI (say: `script1`) to launch a file-deletion process (contained in `script2`). In order to run successfully `script2` needs to run with sudo rights.

`script2` will itterate over a long list of files and delete them. But I need it to communicate with the GUI contained in `script1` after each round so that `script1` can update the progressbar.

In it's absolute most basic form my **current working setup** looks like this:

Script1:

```
import io
from threading import Thread
import subprocess

import wx

# a whole lot of wx GUI stuff 

def get_password():
    """Retrieve user password via a GUI"""

    # A wx solution using wx.PasswordEntryDialog()
    # Store password in a variable

    return variable

class run_script_with_sudo(Thread):
    """Launch a script with administrator privileges"""

    def __init__(self, path_to_script, wx_pubsub_sendmessage):
        """Set variables to self"""
        self.path = path_to_script
        self.sender = wx_pubsub_sendmessage
        self.password = get_password()
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        """Run thread"""

        prepare_script = subprocess.Popen(["echo", password], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        prepare_script.wait()
        launch_script = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', '-S', '/usr/local/bin/python3.6', '-u', self.path], stdin=prepare_script.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        for line in io.TextIOWrapper(launch_script.stdout, encoding="utf-8"):
            print("Received line: ", line.rstrip())
            # Tell progressbar to add another step:
            wx.CallAfter(self.sender, "update", msg="")
```

Script2:

```
import time

# This is a test setup, just a very simple loop that produces an output.

for i in range(25):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(i)
```

The above setup works in that `script1` receives the output of `script2` in real-time and acts on it. (So in the given example: after each second `script1` adds another step to the progress bar until it reaches 25 steps).

**What I want to achieve** = not storing the password in a variable and using macOS it's native GUI to retrieve the password.

However when I change:

```
prepare_script = subprocess.Popen(["echo", password], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
prepare_script.wait()
launch_script = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', '-S', '/usr/local/bin/python3.6', '-u', self.path], stdin=prepare_script.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in io.TextIOWrapper(launch_script.stdout, encoding="utf-8"):
                print("Received line: ", line.rstrip())
                # Tell progressbar to add another step:
                wx.CallAfter(self.sender, "update", msg="")
```

Into:

```
command = r"""/usr/bin/osascript -e 'do shell script "/usr/local/bin/python3.6 -u """ + self.path + """ with prompt "Sart Deletion Process " with administrator privileges'"""
command_list = shlex.split(command)

launch_script = subprocess.Popen(command_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in io.TextIOWrapper(launch_script.stdout, encoding="utf-8"):
    print("Received line: ", line.rstrip())
    # Tell progressbar to add another step:
    wx.CallAfter(self.sender, "update", msg="")
```

It stops working because osascript apparently [runs in a non-interactive shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49156646/4041795). This means `script2` doesn't sent any output until it is fully finished, causing the progress bar in `script1` to stall.

**My question thus becomes**: How can I make sure to use macOS native GUI to ask for the sudo password, thus preventing having to store it in a variable, while still maintaining the possibility to catch the stdout from the privileged script in an interactive / real-time stream.

Hope that makes sense.

Would appreciate any insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **My question thus becomes**: How can I make sure to use macOS native GUI
>   to ask for the sudo password, thus preventing having to store it in a
>   variable, while still maintaining the possibility to catch the stdout
>   from the privileged script in an interactive / real-time stream.

I have found a solution myself, using a **named pipe** (`os.mkfifo()`).

That way, you can have 2 python scripts communicate with each other while 1 of them is launched with privileged rights via osascript (meaning: you get a native GUI window that asks for the users sudo password).

**Working solution**:

*mainscript.py*

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import shlex
import subprocess
import sys
from threading import Thread
import time

class LaunchDeletionProcess(Thread):

    def __init__(self):

        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):

        launch_command = r"""/usr/bin/osascript -e 'do shell script "/usr/local/bin/python3.6 -u /path/to/priviliged_script.py" with prompt "Sart Deletion Process " with administrator privileges'"""
        split_command = shlex.split(launch_command)

        print("Thread 1 started")
        testprogram = subprocess.Popen(split_command)
        testprogram.wait()
        print("Thread1 Finished")

class ReadStatus(Thread):

    def __init__(self):

        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):

        while not os.path.exists(os.path.expanduser("~/p1")):
            time.sleep(0.1)

        print("Thread 2 started")

        self.wfPath = os.path.expanduser("~/p1")

        rp = open(self.wfPath, 'r')
        response = rp.read()

        self.try_pipe(response)

    def try_pipe(self, response):
        rp = open(self.wfPath, 'r')
        response = rp.read()
        print("Receiving response: ", response)
        rp.close()
        if response == str(self.nr_of_steps-1):
            print("Got to end")
            os.remove(os.path.expanduser("~/p1"))
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.try_pipe(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    thread1 = LaunchDeletionProcess()
    thread2 = ReadStatus()
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
```

*priviliged_script.py*

```
import os
import time
import random

wfPath = os.path.expanduser("~/p1")

try:

    os.mkfifo(wfPath)

except OSError:

    print("error")
    pass

result = 10

nr = 0 

while nr < result:

    random_nr = random.random()

    wp = open(wfPath, 'w')
    print("writing new number: ", random_nr)
    wp.write("Number: " + str(random_nr))       
    wp.close()

    time.sleep(1)
    nr += 1

wp = open(wfPath, 'w')
wp.write("end")     
wp.close()
```